# How do I download the certificate from a web server that is self signed using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I've found several answer about how to download the certificate for a website in PowerShell using TcpClient.

```
function Get-RemoteCertificate {
       
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate])]
    param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
      [ValidateNotNull()]
      [Uri]$Uri
    )

    process {
        try {# connecting
            $TcpClient = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($Uri.Host, $Uri.Port)
    
            try {# getting SSL
                $SslStream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new($TcpClient.GetStream())
                $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($Uri.Host)
                $SslStream.RemoteCertificate
            } finally {
                $SslStream.Dispose()
            }# end SSL
    
        } finally {
            $TcpClient.Dispose()
        }# end connect
    }
}
```

But as the TLS handshake will fail when the certificate isn't trusted, I can't download self signed certificates and I will get the error

```
Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to 
respond
```

Is there a way to download self signed certificates without using OpenSSL?

Comment: You are not showing how you are setting your connection. SSL-site requires this at the top of your script: ***  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]:: Tls12 ***.  Are you saying the site is not SSL?

Comment: *"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to 
respond"*  - this error does not look like a certificate problem to me. The TCP connection already fails, which means it will not even try TLS and thus no certificates are involved here.

Comment: @postanote As I said, this isn't my code. But if you try it out on a site with a public certificate you will see that you get the certifcate... To connect to i.e. google, just enter `$TcpClient = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new('www.google.com', 443)` `$SslStream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new($TcpClient.GetStream())`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's the only difference. Try it out on a site that you know are using a self signed certificate.

Comment: @Dennis: *"But if you try it out on a site with a public certificate you will see that you get the certifcate... To connect to i.e. google ...."* - You comparing a site which is not reachable and has a self-signed certificate against a site which is reachable and has a publicly trusted certificate. Try instead a site which is reachable and has a self-signed certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Of course the site is reachable. `Invoke-WebRequest 'URI' -SkipCertificateCheck` is ok. That is not the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is using an old HttpWebRequest that is depreciated and will not work with powershell 7.
Taken from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70623255/2254425):

> The `HttpWebRequest` API surface has not been fully ported to the newer versions of .NET/Core, as detailed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29301):
>
> > `HttpWebRequest` is API which is obsolete - see https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0003.md.
> > We ported only the most important parts of it to .NET Core.
> > **The recommended Networking API is `HttpClient`**.

Without using your sample, you can achieve this simple task based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253055/powershell-script-to-get-certificate-expiry-for-a-website-remotely-for-multiple)

```
$ub = new-object System.UriBuilder -argumentlist 'https', '1.1.1.1', 443
$uri = $ub.Uri

# Disable the verification: 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri.AbsoluteUri)
try {
    $req.GetResponse() | Out-Null
    # Export the file, or return it if you want to keep a function
    $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.Export("Cert") | Set-Content -Path "C:\temp\test.crt"  -Encoding Byte
} catch {
    Write-Host Exception while checking URL $url`: $_ -f Red
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to transform/replace my URI using `$uri = $ub.Uri`? I.e. Google would be [URI]$Uri = 'www.google.com'`. I don't understand where to enter the FQDN.

Comment: it's just because in your sample you were using [Uri]$Uri as an argument. So I used an UriBuilder to get an URI Object, the FQDN in the example is "1.1.1.1".
If you only want to supply the `$Uri = "https://www.google.com"`  replace this line `$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri.AbsoluteUri)` with `$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Uri)`

Comment: Works like a charm in PoSH 5.1 :) (but it fails in PWSH 7.2.x)

Comment: You're totally right. Seems like the HttpWebRequest API is depreciated, I will edit my answer to add a warning.

Comment: I don't need to use $req.EndGetResponse("some_arg_I_don't_know") to avoid memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This is [considered dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613434) and you should think about the possible negative side effects of using this technique.

You can use a different overload when instantiating `[System.Net.Security.SslStream]` that ignores cert errors as shown here.

```
function Get-RemoteCertificate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Uri]$Uri
    )

    process {
        try {
            $TcpClient = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($Uri.Host, $Uri.Port)
            try {
                $SslStream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new(
                    $TcpClient.GetStream(),
                    $True,
                    [System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback]{$true}
                )
                $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($Uri.Host)
                $SslStream.RemoteCertificate
            } finally {
                $SslStream.Dispose()
            }
        } finally {
            $TcpClient.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 12 |              $TcpClient = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($Uri.Hos …  | Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.